# Any Danger of Unjoined Threads in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm working on an SDK for Android with a few threads involve. I have an operation that creates and starts an unreferenced thread as so:

```
new MySdkThread().start();
```

I have to be absolutely certain that I'm not creating any sort of zombie thread and/or memory leak. So is a thread that has returned from it's `run()` method dead and as such if it is unreferenced is it now eligible for reclamation by the garbage collector or do I have to join it? I realize that this is probably a very obvious answer, but I haven't found anything being absolutely specific about the requirements of joining a thread and I want to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is a thread that has returned from it's run() method dead and as such if it is unreferenced is it now eligible for reclamation by the garbage collector or do I have to join it?

No you don't have to join with it.  If there are no references held to the `Thread` object then it will be reclaimed by the garbage collected automatically and you don't have to worry about it at all.  That's standard operation procedure.